# On demand image load using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

suppose i have div and div has many images like

```
<div id="main">
<img src="~/images/img_1.png">
<img src="~/images/img_2.png">
<img src="~/images/img_3.png">
<img src="~/images/img_4.png">
<img src="~/images/img_5.png">
<img src="~/images/img_6.png">
</div>


$('DIV.example').each(function() {
if(this.complete) {
//remove spinner and show actual image
}
});
```

when all the above images in particular div will be loading then i want to show spinner busy image and which will has completely downloaded in client then i want to show actual image instead of spinner.

i want code in such way to detect which image has completely download and then replace the spinner image url with actual image for a particular div not for all images in my pages.

thanks

---

does it works....someone suggest me this code.

```
<div id="main">
<img src="~/images/busy.png" data-src='"~/images/img_1.png"'>
<img src="~/images/busy.png" data-src='"~/images/img_2.png"'>
<img src="~/images/busy.png" data-src='"~/images/img_3.png"'>
<img src="~/images/busy.png" data-src='"~/images/img_4.png"'>
<img src="~/images/busy.png" data-src='"~/images/img_5.png"'>
</div>

$('#main img').each(function() {
   $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('data-src'));
}).removeAttr('data-src');
```

how to determine here data-src image file has been downloaded or not? plzz guide. thanks

```
thisTab.find('img[data-src]').each(function() {
$(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-src'))
       .removeAttr('data-src');
```

});

Comment: I would look at the [jQuery Load() method](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event to detect if the element has been loaded or not. For example,

CSS

```
#main img { display: none; }
```

JS

```
$('#main img').each(function() {
   var loader = $('<img src="/images/loader.gif" />');
   $(this).after(loader).load(function() { loader.remove(); $(this).show(); });
   loader.show();
});
```

Comment: some suggest me the code like -- <div id="main">
<img src="~/images/busy.png" data-src='"~/images/img_1.png"'>
<img src="~/images/busy.png" data-src='"~/images/img_2.png"'>
<img src="~/images/busy.png" data-src='"~/images/img_3.png"'>
<img src="~/images/busy.png" data-src='"~/images/img_4.png"'>
<img src="~/images/busy.png" data-src='"~/images/img_5.png"'>
</div>


 $('#main img').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('data-src'));
 }).removeAttr('data-src');
does it work? how can i detect data-src images has been downloaded or not? plzz guide me. thanks for ur code.

Comment: @user750398, the idea of the said code is that browser will display busy image at first and then when you change the src, it will download new image and then show that when its loaded. So essentially, you need not track the loading of images. Just check if it works or not.

Comment: the above piece of code u gave will automatically invoke or do i need to put in any function and later call the function to execute the code. i want that whenever any image will be added in #main div then your code should fire to download the actual image. so tell me your code gets execute automatically or not or do i need to call it explicitly........thanks

Answer (score 1):

Updated the example without testing.

HTML

> < div class=main >
>
> < div class=main >
>
> < div class=main >
>
> < div class=main >

u could use asp:listview to render the html.

css:

> ```
> background: url('spinner.gif') no-repeat center center;
> width: 30px;
> height: 30px;
> display: inline;
> float: left;
> position: relative;
> ```

js function

> function imageLoad() {
>
> ```
>         var loader = $('.main');
>
>         loader.each(function(i){
>             var img = new Image();
>             $(img).load(
>                  function() {
>                      $(this).hide();
>
>                      loader[i].append(this);
>
>                      $(this).fadeIn(1000);
>              })
>
>
>             $(img).attr('src', 'ur/actual/image/url');
>          })
>
>
>     }
> ```

Comment: ur code looks good but how can i use it for many images in my div? give the code for that. thanks